# Setting matrix cell styles from within the matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-matrix

I'm programmatically generating a tikz matrix, and sometimes, when I've generated one cell, I learn something from that which is going to affect how I style a later cell. So, I want to be able to call a tikzset command that fixes the particular cell's style. Something like:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes] {
    hello \tikzset{row 1 column 2/.style={red}}& world \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

would render the word "world" in red. It doesn't and I assume that this is due to some sort of grouping level. I can get around it by issuing a global command

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes] {
    hello {\globaldefs=1%
    \tikzset{row 1 column 2/.style={red}}}& world \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This sets the style for all subsequent tikzpictures as well (see full MWE below). Of course, I can unset the style later, but this feels inelegant. Is there a better way to set the style (from within one cell to affect a *different*, later cell) so that it only applies to the current matrix or tikzpicture?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
%direct setting of the style doesn't work
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes] {
    hello \tikzset{row 1 column 2/.style={red}}& world \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
%setting the global style works, but...
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes] {
    hello {\globaldefs=1%
    \tikzset{row 1 column 2/.style={red}}}& world \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
%...style is not local (obviously) and remains in effect on later pictures
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes] {
    hello & world \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can insert `|[options list]|` in any cell to decide particular options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
%direct setting of the style doesn't work
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes] {
    hello &|[red]| world \\
    hello &|[green, draw, font=\bfseries]| hello\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]